# Open source pic programmer in windows

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming

I started a project with my students to build a full open source PIC IDE in windows. My first try was to port [Piklab](http://piklab.sourceforge.net/) to windows but it is dependent on Qt and KDE. We decide then to use [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) as IDE, SDCC as compiler and GPUtils as linker and assembler. We managed to make the compiler-chain plugin so we can build the whole project in eclipse and generate the binary.

The problem now is how to use eclipse to program the PIC (we are targeting specifically on ICD2 because it is what we have available on our lab). Does anyone knows an open-source programmer that can run on command line on windows?

Thanks

Comment: well done!  I know I tried to the same a few years back - but my lack of eclipse programming skills were my downfall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [piklab-prog.exe](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/piklab/index.php?title=Command-line_Utility) in the piklab package?  Its a CLI tool for programming.

Alternatively the PicKit 2 has a stand alone CLI tool direct from microchip.

Comment: Hi. I've tryed to use piklab-prog.exe, but it depends on LubUSB, which somehow didn't worked for me.

Comment: Although I'm having some troubles, it seems the best alternative until MPLAB X.

Answer (score 3):

Microchip is developing a new version of MPLAB based on netbeans called [MPLAB X](http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplab%3a_start). This will be their cross-platform open source IDE going forward.

Comment: Then i think that I'll should wait a little more with my project!

Comment: MPLAB X has entered public beta: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/mplab/X_Beta/index.html

Answer (score 2):

What about using the [PicProg](http://hyvatti.iki.fi/%7Ejaakko/pic/picprog.html)?

You can use commands like this:

```
picprog [/h] [/log] [/info] [/list] [/init2] [/standby] [/read] [/continue] [/compare] [/noF84] [lpt1|lpt2] [/w:FILENAME]
```

**Parameter definition:**

> **/h**    help
>
> **/log**    write output to picprog.log, forces /info
>
> **/info**    show full programming information
>
> **/list**    list of supported PIC
>
> **/init2**    use /MCLR before Vpp power-up mode
>
> **/standby**    loop program
>
> **/continue**    continue programming also while errors occur
>
> **/noF84**    blocks PIC16F84 mode
>
> **/lptX**    definition of parallel port
>
> **/read**    data transfer from pic to file, reverses /w: command
>
> **/compare**    data comparison of pic and file, overrides /w: command
>
> **/w:**    erase and write PIC, uses hex-file, extension will be ignored and set to .hex

You can find more information about open source tools (in portuguese) at this site: http://www.sergioprado.org/2010/06/17/ferramentas-open-source-para-pic/

Answer (score 1):

The PICkit 2 has source-available firmware and host application.  The firmware is not true OSI-approved Open Source as its use is restricted to Microchip's products.  There are alternative command-line tools that are Free software.  Many PICkit 2 clones are available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what devices you want to program, but Travis Goodspeed's GoodFET (Open hardware, open source) tool has some support for PICs (even though it's focused on the MSP430 line).

Check out http://goodfet.sourceforge.net/apps/pic/.

Answer (score 1):

The firmware and host software for [our PIC programmers](http://www.embedinc.com/products) is available via [free download](http://www.embedinc.com/picprg/sw.htm).  The [interface spec](http://www.embedinc.com/picprg/picprg_prot.txt.htm) is also publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

My Wisp648 is open-source in the sense that the circuit, firmware and PC software are all available in source. I sell this programmer, but you are allowed to build your own version. You are *not* allowed to sell clones. I dunno whether this qualifies as open source in your book.

The PC side software is written in Python. It has both a command line interface and a GUI. Some other people have written their own versions of the PC side software, for instance xwisp2 and bumblebee.

http://www.voti.nl/wisp648

http://www.voti.nl/xwisp